# UFW blocking connection despite it beeing configured to allow it

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I am in the processes of setting up a VPN server on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

In the process I enabled `ufw`.

I already had some applications on the machine listening on different ports.
One of these applications listening on port `9080` is now blocked. Trying to open the previously available website now results in a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`-Error.

On port `8080` I have another application running. This website I can open without any problems. The only difference between those (despite the port) is that one is using http the other https.

My complete `ufw status`:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
1194/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
9022/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8384/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
9080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
9080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1194/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9022/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8384/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
9080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem.

What I didn't mention was that both applications run inside a Docker container.
Apparently Docker directly alters the iptables. To make it work with ufw it is necessary to forward all Docker traffic running this command `ufw allow in on docker0`.